# Error no conecta con la unidad de persistencia JPA

Tags: jpa

No logro conectar con la unidad de persistencia
**codigo y manejador de entidades**

```
public class AlumnoDAO 
{
   private EntityManager daogenerico;


public void  conectar()
{
   daogenerico=Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("EscuelaPU").createEntityManager();
}


public boolean crearAlumno(Alumnos a)
{
  try
  {
      conectar();
      daogenerico.getTransaction().begin();
      daogenerico.persist(a);
      daogenerico.getTransaction().commit();
      return true;

  }catch(Exception e)

  {
     daogenerico.getTransaction().rollback();
     return false;
  }

}
}
```

**El siguiente es la excepcion que arroja en consola**

> Exception Description: Cannot acquire data source [Escuela].
>   Internal Exception: javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'Escuela' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming} [Root exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Escuela not found]
>   Advertencia:   StandardWrapperValve[Controlador]: Servlet.service() for servlet Controlador threw exception
>   java.lang.NullPointerException

**Archivo xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <persistence 
version="2.1" xmlns="xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" 
xmlns:xsi="w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence xmlns.jcp.org/xml
/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd"> <persistence-unit name="EscuelaPU" 
transaction-type="JTA"> <jta-data-source>Escuela</jta-data-source> 
<exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes> <properties/> 
</persistence-unit> </persistence>
```

Comment: Lograste resolver el problema?

Comment: no aun no @RaulCacacho he revisado por muchas partes pero no encuentro la solucion

Comment: Lo que veo es que no estas usando EscuelaPU en vez de Escuela

Comment: el jndi me solicita un nombre ese es el nombre de la presistencia

Comment: Pero se usa ese que te digo para hacer las consultas

Comment: Intenta poniendo a `true` la opción de `exclude-unlisted-classes` y agrega manualmente todas las entidades.